# Try/catch in JSP fails

Tags: java, jsp

A try/catch statement in my Java code (embedded in JSP) fails with the following error:

```
An error occurred at line: 26 in the jsp file: /template/tampabay/includes/omniture-footer.jsp
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

I am unable to determine why the following code produces that error:

```
<%!
    /*
     * Map the DTI categories to the appropriate SiteCatalyst category
     * structure.
     */
    ArrayList<HashMap> mapDTIToSiteCatalystCategories( ArrayList<HashMap> dti_categories ) {
        ArrayList<HashMap> site_catalyst_categories = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
        ArrayList<Integer> dti_category_ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
            try {
                dti_category_ids.add( Integer.parseInt( (String)dti_categories.get( i ).get( "id" ) ) );
            }
            catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
                dti_category_ids.add( -1 );
            }
        }
        // - Snip -
    }
```

The error corresponds to the twelfth line above ( the closing brace of the `try` statement ). However, the code looks syntactically correct to me. Aside from breach of protocol by embedding a scriptlet in JSP, can you help point out the error?

I have tried using variations of this code (removing the `for` loop and declaring separate variables) but the error persists whenever I try to use the try/catch statement.

**EDIT**:

I uploaded [the complete code listing here.](http://pastebin.com/HU1Xr3g7)

**EDIT 2**:
I also receive the following error:

```
An error occurred at line: 44 in the jsp file: /template/tampabay/includes/omniture-footer.jsp
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
```

This error corresponds to the fourth line below:

```
              "", "Baseball",
              "", ""
        );
    break;
case 120: // Baseball: Minors
    site_catalyst_categories = addElements(
        dti_category_ids.get( 0 ), "Sports",
```

I did not include it before because I assumed it was caused by the earlier error. However, in light of the comments, it may be relevant.

According to my IDE and my visual inspection, all of the braces are properly paired. However, the compiler disagrees.

Comment: This is correct, I would like to see the - snip - portion

Comment: Are you terminating your code-block with %>

Comment: Why are you using scriptlets?! :(

Comment: @Gnostus: I updated the question with a link to the complete code.

Comment: @das_weezul: Yes. Please see the complete code listing.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: That's an internal political issue. I'll have to tackle it later.

Comment: 1. underscores 2. spaces around arguments 3. scriptlets - you should really reconsider that code style policies

Comment: @Bozho: I agree with your observations (except the spaces around arguments, for readability's sake). This is an inherited project on a high-traffic, and the cleanup will take some time. The immediate problem is of greater importance for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, on line 131/132, there's a missing close curly for the try statement.

```
                    case 131:
                        try {
                            switch ( dti_category_ids.get( 2 ) ) {
                               case 252: // Colleges: Bulls ..snip..
                               case 253: // Colleges: Bulls ..snip..
                               case 254: // Colleges: Bulls ..snip..
                               default: // Log all others to the "College" section
                            }
                            break;
                        // HERE ... THERE'S NO } TO CLOSE THE try {
                        catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
                            // Log all others to the "College" section
                            site_catalyst_categories = addElements(
                                    dti_category_ids.get( 0 ), "Sports",
                                    "", "College",
                                    "", "",
                                    "", ""
                                );

                        }
```

Comment: Good eye. After fixing this and removing the extra two lines at 218/219, the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, try to use an editor that will re-indent the source for you. Then you can tell it "re-indent the whole file" and look for where everything looks too far to the right/left, or even just all wonky. I didn't use it for this, but I've used that functionality in the past (for all kinds of different languages).